# Angular production error while building the project

Tags: angular

$ ng build --prod
Date: 2018-12-06T18:43:56.689Z
Hash: e36e17503416de0fc128
Time: 7480ms
chunk {0} runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js (runtime) 1.44 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.9868d9b237c3a48c54da.js (main) 128 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.85f47f0bf59079cbc23a.js (polyfills) 130 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} styles.94b23734c15b9fde9994.css (styles) 128 kB [initial] [rendered]
ERROR in src\app\app.component.html(25,29): : Property 'savedSearches' does not exist on type 'object'.
src\app\app.component.html(75,73): : Property 'savedSearches' does not exist on type 'object'.
src\app\app.component.html(115,66): : Property 'predefinedSearches' does not exist on type 'object'.
src\app\app.component.html(126,66): : Property 'categories' does not exist on type 'object'.
src\app\app.component.html(155,66): : Property 'activities' does not exist on type 'object'.
src\app\app.component.html(165,66): : Property 'facilities' does not exist on type 'object'.

Comment: Please include the relevant code as well.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What code did you use? What did you already try to do to resolve the problem?

Comment: this is because you have used some properties in HTML which you are not define in ts

Comment: export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    ngOnInit(){
    this.getSearches();
    this.getResults();
  }
  search: object;
  searchResults: object;
  savedSearches: string;

  constructor(private activityService : ActivityService) {}
  getSearches(){
    this.activityService.getSearchAPI()
    .subscribe(
      data => this.search = data,
      error => console.log('Server Error')
    );
  }
    }

Comment: <div class="col-4">
   <div class="dropdown">
    <label for="savedSearch" style="margin-left: 5%;">Saved Search</label>
    <select class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" style="margin-left: 20%;" id="savedSearch">
 <option>Choose a Saved Search</option>
  <option value="savedSearchName" *ngFor="let sav of search?.savedSearches">{{sav.savedSearchName}}</option>
    </select>
   </div>
 </div>

Comment: Those are my app.component.ts and app.component.html code snippets. Not sure why even after declaring savedSearches in my app.component.ts file am still getting the same error.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of providing more details in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because your variable types are just "object" - which does't have a "savedSearches" property. You need to either create a class that has those properties or use bracket notation.

```
*ngFor="let sav of search['savedSearches']"
```

Personally, I prefer to create a class because it's clearer what fields the variables actually have. You are using TypeScript after all.

```
class SearchResult {
    savedSearches: SavedSearch[];
}

class SavedSearch {
    savedSearchName: string;
}

AppComponent implements OnInit {         
    search: SearchResult;

    constructor(private activityService : ActivityService) {} 

    ngOnInit(){ this.getSearches(); this.getResults(); } 

    getSearches(){ 
      this.activityService.getSearchAPI()
          .subscribe( 
              data => this.search = data,
              error => console.log('Server Error') ); 
          }
      }
}
```

With a class, your template can remain the same:

```
<div class="col-4">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <label for="savedSearch" style="margin-left: 5%;">Saved Search</label>
        <select class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" style="margin-left: 20%;" id="savedSearch">
            <option>Choose a Saved Search</option>
            <option value="savedSearchName" *ngFor="let sav of search?.savedSearches">{{sav.savedSearchName}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```